# Why STIntersects return 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm running this query in SSMS where a point intersects a polygon, the SQL function "STIntersects()" must return 1, but it returns 0

```
DECLARE @g geography;  
 DECLARE @h geography;  
 SET @g =GEOGRAPHY::Point(9.8499, -84.0411, 4326);
 SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-84.0494406017199 9.85708639515816, -84.0469829246654 9.85463363328602, -84.0456619682484 9.85434503750654, -84.0443722218354 9.8543235807814, -84.0427261659893 9.85478534522361, -84.0406081294694 9.85484803300104, -84.0392907431181 9.85402763614825, -84.0381025400339 9.85331130049088, -84.0373104803828 9.85239574971867, -84.0368381746276 9.85116820122127, -84.037256275447 9.84974490792287, -84.0383500752008 9.84779707617002, -84.03914044362 9.84702967778441, -84.0392307023021 9.84634795081857, -84.0391879430972 9.84631193525619, -84.0385231204147 9.84543208576742, -84.039023072582 9.84462172322902, -84.0404387881086 9.8437176020834, -84.0412092682637 9.84422405674464, -84.0419096009237 9.84526744796677, -84.0427005458733 9.84540219337767, -84.0435273373874 9.84557253131655, -84.044350835467 9.84701301301609, -84.0448023039011 9.84793242261307, -84.0454288381811 9.84858933524013, -84.0463628360415 9.84895497456596, -84.0477332494427 9.8490747814008, -84.0506662239194 9.84940037660295)', 4326);  

 SELECT @g.STIntersects(@h);
```

This is the spacial result:
[SQL Spacial Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAf7E.png)

Why is this happening?

Comment: your line string seems  not intersecting the point  .. check better  .. or coudl be you are looking for a polygon

Comment: I want to know if the point is inside the polygon

Comment: then use (in proper way)  POLYGON and not LINESTRING